# How to get download file from Laravel 5.1 with AngularJS and ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel-5, restangular

I have this code in laravel for export excel:

```
public function export_excel(Request $request){      
    $user = user::all();
    Excel::create('user', function($excel) use($user) {
        $excel->sheet('Sheet 1', function($sheet) use($user) {
            $sheet->fromArray($user);
        });
    })->download('xls');
}
```

and my route is:

```
Route::get('user/export/excel','UserController@export_excel');
```

and my html is:

```
<a><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> Export to Excel</a>
```

I want to send request from REST API with `Restangular` and after that get download file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved problem with this:

```
this.downloadExcel = function(){
        Restangular.one('user/export/excel').withHttpConfig({responseType: 'blob'}).get().then(function(response) {
             var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(response);
             window.open(url,"_self");
        })
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simple use the href attribute

```
<a href="user/export/excel" target="_BLANK">
   <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> Export to Excel
</a>
```